# Paperclip not saving photo to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

New to web development and have been trying to solve this for 4 days now - been through every solution here on StackOverflow but none of the answers have worked for me.

I am creating an application that allows users to upload an attachment and photo through Paperclip.  Authentication and Authorization through Devise and CanCan

From a edit page, a user can click on a link to open an 'edit' page.  From there he can see a form to browse and choose an image to upload. When clicking on the button, it calls the 'update' action and then renders the users show page, the image is saved to a tmp folder but does not insert to the Database.

Here is my User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
        thumb:  '50x50>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '300x300>'
    }

def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end

# Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

User Controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :get_user, :only => [:index, :new, :edit]
before_action :accessible_roles, :only => [:new, :edit, :show, :update, :create]
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:show, :new, :destroy, :edit, :update]

def index
  @users = User.accessible_by(current_ability, :index).limit(20)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @users }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    format.html
  end
end

def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @users }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    format.html
  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @users }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    format.html
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
end

def edit
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @users }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    format.html
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
end

def destroy
  @user.destroy!

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { respond_to_destroy(:ajax) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
    format.html { respond_to_destroy(:html) }
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @users.to_json, :status => 200 }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :text => "Could not create user", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { render :action => :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  if params[:user][:password].blank?
    [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password].collect{|p| params[:user].delete(p) }
  else
    @user.errors[:base] << "The password you entered is incorrect" unless @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
     if @user.errors[:base].empty? and @user.update_attributes(user_params[:user])
        flash[:notice] = "Your account has been updated"
          format.json { render :json => @user.to_json, :status => 200 }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { render :action => :show }
     else
        format.json { render :text => "Could not update user", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render :action => :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
end

private

def accessible_roles
   @accessible_roles = Role.accessible_by(current_ability, :read)
end

def get_user
  @user = current_user 
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :resume)
end
end
```

Here is the form code:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="field">

  <%= f.label :avatar, "Photo" %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

I can not even seem to get it to display the temp image.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
<%= @user.email %>
```

Comment: can we see the view and how you are trying to render the image please?

Comment: out of interest why is there no `@user = User.find()params[:id]` in your edit action and no `@user = User.new` in your new action ?

Comment: Added the simple view code.

Comment: The edit and new actions seem to be working through Devise and the get_user method once signed in.  I am new to this so would that be a potential problem?  I'm trying to fix one thing at a time as it breaks.

Comment: so you have a users controller and devise handling user authentication ?

Comment: Yes.  And also using CanCan for authorization.

Comment: can a user only add an image when updating their profile?

Comment: I eventually also want to add the ability to upload another attachment.  But I had planned user to upload photos and attachments only after accounts have been created already.

Comment: take a look at overriding devise controllers, google will give you a lot of answers

Comment: I'll take a look.  Does it matter that I had commented out the registration controller in my routes file?                        devise_for :users#, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" } ## Code used to restrict user registration

Comment: tbh it sounds like there's a lot going on that shouldn't be..my advice, make a new branch, use just devise for authentication (adding user roles to devise is easy without can can IMHO)